# Join two table sqlplus, sharing column names, returning NULL

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have three tables that I am trying to join to look like

student_id, first_name, last_name, club_id, club_name.

There are members who are active in one club, but inactive in another club, so the member will appear in both active and inactive tables. There is also a member that is not active in any club, but I need to return their id, first_name, and last_name.
My code currently does not return the member info with NULL in club_id.

```
active_member(student_id(PK), first_name, last_name, club_id(FK))

inactive_member(student_id(PK), first_name, last_name, club_id(FK))

member_club(club_id(PF), club_name,) 

SELECT a.student_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, c.club_id, c.club_name
FROM active_member a, member_club c
WHERE c.club_id = a.club_id
UNION ALL
SELECT b.student_id, b.first_name, b.last_name, c.club_id, c.club_name
FROM member_club c, inactive_member b
WHERE c.club_id = b.club_id;
```

Comment: What is the problem is not visible. Could you add sample data and expected result. Your approach seems to be fine with `union all`

Answer (score 1):

NULLs cannot be compared as a value as null means the value does not exist to compare against.

You can either surround with brackets and use an OR IS NULL check...

OR, I prefer to use NVL() and turn it into a value instead when it doesn't exist e.g. `NVL(c.club_id, -1) = NVL(b.club_id, -1)`

Here is an example Fiddle showing the NVL() option:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f41750/9/0

--- UPDATE: ---

The above assumes there IS a row in the join table. If the row doesn't exist then you need to outer join the tables.
e.g. use (+) after the table that may not have a row, e.g.

```
SELECT a.student_id, a.first_name, a.last_name, c.club_id, c.club_name
FROM active_member a, member_club c
WHERE c.club_id = a.club_id(+)
UNION ALL
SELECT b.student_id, b.first_name, b.last_name, c.club_id, c.club_name
FROM member_club c, inactive_member b
WHERE c.club_id = b.club_id(+);
```

I don't know your data so you will need to apply it to the correct table.